# Trying to SSH in using urxvt gives error

Tags: ssh

Every other terminal I've tried has worked fine and has displayed colours and such correctly, but whenever I log in using urxvt I get the following error

```
tput: unknown terminal "rxvt-unicode-256color"
tput: unknown terminal "rxvt-unicode-256color"
tput: unknown terminal "rxvt-unicode-256color"
```

Whenever I try to `clear` I get the following error

```
'rxvt-unicode-256color': unknown terminal type.
```

And some programs such as `nano` won't start at all, giving this error

```
Error opening terminal: rxvt-unicode-256color.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

I'd guess that `rxvt` provides a superset of `xterm` capabilities, so this should be okay, and will be recognized by `tput`.  It only applies to the current shell and its children, so if it causes a problem you can just close it.

If it works you can add it to `~/.profile` so you do not have to keep doing it over again -- although note that this requires you log in again and in some contexts may not work, you can check easily with `echo $TERM`.

Comment: Thank you, export TERM=xterm-256color fixed it short term, and adding it to .bash_profile rather than .profile fixed it on future logins

Answer (score 6):

### TERMINFO

Install the appropriate entry into the terminfo database

According to [the ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rxvt-unicode)

> If you are logging into a remote host, you may encounter problems when running text-mode programs under `rxvt-unicode`. This can be fixed by installing `rxvt-unicode-terminfo` on the remote host or by copying `/usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode` from your local machine to your host at `~/.terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode`; same for `rxvt-unicode-256color`.

As goldilocks noted in their answer. It is very likely that urxvt has sufficient in common with xterm that it can use an xterm terminfo entry mostly OK.